# How to inject ssh options to pip install git+ssh

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, pip, ansible

I have a newely provisioned AWS instance. I am trying to install an application using the `pip install git+ssh syntax` using ansible. However, ansible hangs. Upon further investigation, ansible hangs because:

`The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`

So my question is, how to inject an ssh option such as `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` into the pip command?

Alternative solutions will also be considered.

Comment: You may want to google for `ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the fingerprint via `ssh-keyscan` and put it into the `known_hosts` file yourself.

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >>~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This way ssh is already happy with the key and you don't have to remember to add options every time.

But if you'd just rather ignore anything fingerprint-related, it should also work if you add the option in your `~/.ssh/config` under the `github.com` host (or in general, but that seems riskier)

```
Host github.com
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing the first, but using the global ssh config on the server.

Comment: That makes sense. That line comes from a Travis test file, so we only cared about the specific run.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing it with `ssh-keyscan`, you can do it with the Ansible `known_hosts` module:

```
- name: Tell the host about our servers it might want to ssh to
  known_hosts:
    path: '/{{ ansible_env.USER }}/.ssh/known_hosts'
    name: 'github.com'
    key: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com') }}"
```

You can also add it system wide: `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`

Hope that helps you

Comment: yeah, that is great!

Comment: The path should be `path: '/{{ ansible_env.USER }}/.ssh/known_hosts'` without the `ssh` prefix